# What is NoPadding equivalent for WiredTiger?

Tags: mongodb, database-design

MongoDB preallocates spaces for document growth. This can be turned off by `noPadding` option but this is applicable to MMAPv1 engine only.

Is there any similar option for WiredTiger engine? I have certain collections that only grows with inserts, so document sizes will always be the same.

I want to keep my collection as small as possible. So if there is any feature of MongoDB that provides space saving (like noPadding) for WiredTiger, I would like to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WiredTiger has no padding, since there are [no in-place updates (see slide 25)](http://de.slideshare.net/wiredtiger/mongo-db-worldwiredtiger). Instead the whole updated document is written to a new location, which is called copy-on-write.

Of course, this causes the data files to be bigger than they need to be. However, in case you use compression (which is turned on by default), that overhead should be rather small.

If you really want to make sure you do not "waste" any space, you can use the [**`compact`** command](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/compact/#dbcmd.compact):

```
use yourDb
db.runCommand({compact:"yourColl"})
```

This [releases unused disk space to the system](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/compact/#wiredtiger), but has the drawback of [blocking the database](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/compact/#blocking) during the operation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can only get the real file size with Zlib compression. That's frustrating. Also, indexes takes the twice size no matter what. Compact helps but not enough. Also, since you mentioned it, when I removed everything in a collection and apply compact and dropIndexes, there is still used space for nothing. Do you have a suggestion for that?

Comment: @stackyname Index files are different. And If you want to remove a collection, simply remove it. The datafiles are then deleted. I am not sure however, what exactly you are trying to achieve. Maybe you should be more clear about that and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I edited my main question. My question in the comment was different from the main question though. I don't want to delete my collection but when I delete some information, I would like to take back my disk space.

Comment: @stackyname If you need to reclaim the overhead of an empty collection, there is most likely something wrong with your storage capacity planning. MongoDB isn't exactly optimized small resources. The way it works, you will always have an overhead. There is no way to reclaim disk space on deletion.

Comment: Alright, that's good to know. I mean, I wish I could get back that space back but at least now I know I shouldn't waste my time for that. Thanks a lot!